# How to add a keydown listener to Ext.field.number?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I wish to add a keydown listener to a number field in Sencha Touch 2 to dynamically check the field for errors rather than waiting until the form is submitted. The number field is a component on form. Looking at the official [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4.0/#!/api/Ext.field.Number), only the keyup event can be listened to.

Is it possible to listen to the standard javascript [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) event and define this custom listener in the initialization function of the form?

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate a bit on why you need the keydown event and nothing else will work. 99% of the time you can come away with Sencha builtin features. If you can't, feel free to search `numberfield.element`'s tree for the input element and add a keydown attribute there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a listener to the input field:

```js
numberField.getComponent().input.on({
  scope: this,
  keydown: 'onKeyDown'
});
```

Then define what you want to do on the method 'onKeyDown'

```js
onKeyDown: function(e, obj) {
  //Your code here
}
```

Be careful, I've run into numerous problems trying to use keyboard functions on different devices, particularly with Android.  After many struggles with this and the lack of standards on number fields I found building a number pad for data entry (as opposed to the various device keypads) was a better solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: This approach seems to work. When testing in Chrome is appears that the correct event to listen for is keypress rather than keydown.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the addListener method?

```
numberField.addListener('keydown', function(){
  alert("key down");
});
```

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4.0/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-addListener

Comment: I use addListener for other events. It only works for the predefined events of a numberfield. keydown is not one of these predefined events.

Comment: @mr_js Can you put the number field inside a container and add the keydown listener on the container?